# Checkbox type with nullable option

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony forms to transfer API request in to DTO object. In my PATCH request i want to have bool field which can be null as well (for bool values there need to be done some action, for null just skip that action)

CheckboxType works only for boolean values so i decided to use ChoiceType like this

```
    $builder
            ->add('is_active', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    null  => null,
                    true  => true,
                    false => false,
                ],
            ])
        ;
```

but it does not accept correctly false values, for false i get null and for null i get null value too. My goal is to accept all 3 values.

In configureOptions functions i have only this option:

```
$resolver->setDefault('data_class', TargetClass::class);
```

and in TargetClass this field is defined as:

```
private mixed $active = null;
```

There is any way in symfony forms how to handle correctly these 3 values: `null, false, true`
They must be as bool|null values

Comment: Try `"Null" => null, "True" => true, "False" => false`. Maybe with better wording for front end as `"Not Set" => null, "Active" => true, "Not Active" => false` Also make sure your *is_active* can be a null type with `?bool`.

Comment: @Bossman i don't want to have string as parameters and bools are not correctly parsed to string

Comment: Not sure I understand you. It is `[NAME] => [VALUE]`. It is a simple choice field. Post your *is_active* setter and getter in your *TargetClass* entity so we can see.